# redirect()->back() laravel redirect to root web

Tags: php, laravel

I've deploy laravel project in Centos, the application its running successfully but i have the problem.

When laravel code redirect()->back();
the return is to page https://mywebsite.com/

my file:

/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myproject/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my .htaccess

```
# Server
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes
```

my alias directory

```
Alias /myproject/var/www/html/litprof/myproject/public
<Directory /var/www/html/litprof/myproject/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: so where do you want ot redirect it

Comment: @bhucho back to previous url

Comment: that's what `redirect()->back();` does, explain what is happening properly, where is it redirecting now, where it should redirect